# Change statusbar color to white in Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar

I currently develop an app with phonegap and need to change the color of the statusbar to white text, right now it is black. I am testing on iOS 10 with the official app from PhoneGap.

The statusbar-plugin is installed, I already have checked via terminal (`cordova plugin ls`). Also, the term `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />` is part of my config.xml.

I tried to change the statusbar with `<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />` in my config.xml for example (I know this won't change the color to white, this was just a try to change the statusbar at all) – nothing has changed. None of the tips I found have changed anything – any ideas how to change the color?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it. Dumb mistake.

I deleted the default elements in `index.html` but forgot to edit the JS in the default `index.js`. After deleting the function which tried to change the missing element in my index, I finally was able to edit the StatusBar with `StatusBar.styleLightContent();`.

Comment: I am facing similar issue in my cordova project, can you please guide me. I have added `cordova-plugin-statusbar` plugin and also set config.xml

`<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />`

Comment: make sure you also have this line <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />